# ASP.NET MVC 3 and URL rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, web-config

I would like to lowercase URL and add a slash to its end.
e.g.

```
mydomain.com/About -> mydomain.com/about/
mydomain.com/about -> mydomain.com/about
```

The reason for this is because Google Analytics treats all these URLs as totally different.
I have the following rewrite rule inside web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect mydomain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't recall the syntax for this off the top of my head, but I wanted to point out that in MVC3 if you use the Url.Action or Url.Route methods they will not create URL's with the case/slash stuff taking care of, so every link click will result in a redirect, which is not good.  The way I've solved this in the past is to actually write a custom route implementation that makes all my route url's seo friendly and can 301 if they aren't.

Comment: Those redirects will also result in false positives if something were going to 404, as they response would be 301 on the first request then 404 on the second, causing unnecessary requests to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to lower case routing using the code in the following blog post:  [Force MVC Route URL to Lowercase](http://coderjournal.com/2008/03/force-mvc-route-url-lowercase/).

If a trailing slash is needed, you can modify the code by adding a second class, e.g., `LowerCaseRouteWithTrailingSlash`, and change the code to check for a trailing slash, adding one if needed.